# passing colormap as argument to function

Tags: python, matplotlib

Apologies if this has been solved elsewhere. Searches on this site, about passing objects to functions lead to c++ related posts. Google results point to entries that concern themselves with generating different colormaps.

#### background

I would like to use matplotlib colormaps to color lineplots. Further, I want to be able to specify *which* colormap, as I call the functrion.

#### approach:

```
import numpy as np, matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [6,7,83,5]]

def plotting_function(data, color_map=plt.cm.viridis, plot_kwds=None)

    colors = color_map(np.linspace(0,1,len(data))

    if plot_kwds is None:
        plt_kwds = {}

    for i, y in enumerate(data):
        x_axis = range(len(y))
        plot_kwds['color'] = colors[i]
        plt.plot(x_axis, y, **plot_kwds)
```

#### expected:

a figure with lines coloured according to viridis.

#### actually:

a figure with lines coloured not according to viridis.

I realise I can fix this by moving `colors = plt.cm.viridis(np.linspace(0,1,len(data))` into the function, but it would be inconvenient to mess with the source code every time I want to change colors.

#### question:

how can I pass a colormap to a custom function? 
Is there a simpler approach to this that I am missing?

I really appreciate help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you see no effect is because you use a different name for your initial dictionary: `plt_kwds` instead of `plot_kwds`

In my opinion, you can simply achieve the desired effect by assigning the colors within the for loop using `color` keyword. You don't need `plot_kwds`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [6,7,83,5]]

def plotting_function(data, color_map=plt.cm.viridis, plot_kwds=None):
    colors = color_map(np.linspace(0,1,len(data)))

    for i, y in enumerate(data):
        x_axis = range(len(y))
        plt.plot(x_axis, y, color=colors[i])

plotting_function(data)
```

[image]

Answering the second question, you can pass the desired color map using for example

```
plotting_function(data, color_map=plt.cm.jet)
```

Comment: well.. that's a little embarrassing... Thanks!